# Vue + Vuex reactivity of dictionary object

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, vuex

I am using Vue + Vuex for managing state.

Lets have store:

```
state: {
  nodes: {}
},
actions: {
  loadNodes ({ commit }, parameter) {
     axios.get('http://URL' + '/nodes', {
        params: {
          name: parameter['name'],
          type: parameter['type']
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        commit('nodeActivity', { uid: parameter['uid'], res: response.data })
    })
  }
},
mutations: {
  nodeActivity (state, data: {uid, res}) {
    Vue.set(state.nodes, data.uid, data.res)
  }
},
getters: {
  getNodes: state => state.nodes
}
```

This is probably okey, in `nodes` there is a dictionary structure `{ id: data }`

Now I have component with hook:

```
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('nodeActivity', { uid: this.$props.uid, name: this.$props.namepar, type: this.$props.typepar })
  }
```

So API call got some data and are asynchronous stored. It works. But I need get specific `uid` something like `this.$store.getters.getNodes[0]` that does not work but `this.$store.getters.getNodes` works properly so I think reactivity is okey thanks to `Vue.set(..)`. Even if I use `const tmp = this.$store.getters.getNodes` (`tmp` contains whole dictionary) and then `tmp2 = tmp[0]`, tmp2 is not reactive. 
I do not know why.
I am starting with Vue so I appreciate tips how to change store design.

Comment: I always use computed properties that point to getters or keys in the store. Did you try that?

Comment: No, because I need that data for chart on the index page of application. It has to load data to store while `create()` and immediately use that data (in `mount()`) to create a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a poor and probably out of design solution. 
I just have `watcher` for a variable that loads data from store, someting like `const tmp = this.$store.getters.getNodes`. When `tmp` changes, I can notify that and assign variable `tmp2 = tmp[number]` so the behaviour is reactive. I find this solution quite hacky.